# React-table not showing newly fetched data when rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-functional-component, react-table-v7

I am trying to use react-table. I have made a useEffect hook which calls an async function which fetches new data on every render and I am passing that data to react-table. But when I reload my page, the data disappears and doesn't show.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
import {useMemo} from 'react'
import Axios from "axios"
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams,Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./ViewRecords.css"
import Moment from "moment"
import { useTable,useGlobalFilter } from 'react-table'
import { GlobalFilter } from './GlobalFilter';



export default function ViewRecords({}) {
    const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);

 



    useEffect(() => {
        fetchRecords();
      }, []);

    const {username}=useParams()
  
   
   
    const cols = [
      {
        accessor: "land_owner",
        Header: "Owner Name"
      },
      {
        accessor: "land_size",
        Header: "Land Size (Acres)"
      },
      {
        accessor: "crop_name",
        Header: "Crop Name"
      },
      {
        accessor: "area_planted",
        Header: "Area Planted (Acres)"
      },
      {
        accessor: "expenses",
        Header: "Total Expenses (Rs)"
      },
      {
        accessor: "sales",
        Header: "Total Sales (Rs)"
      },
      {
        accessor: "date_planted",
        Header: "Date Planted",Cell: ({ value }) => {
          return Moment(value).format("LL")
        }
      },
      {
        accessor: "date_harvested",
        Header: "Date Harvested",Cell: ({ value }) => {
          return Moment(value).format("LL")
        }
      },
      
    ];
    const columns = useMemo(() => cols,[])
    const data = useMemo(() => records, [])
    const {
      getTableProps,
      getTableBodyProps,
      headerGroups,
      rows,
      prepareRow,
      state,
      setGlobalFilter,
    } = useTable({
      columns,
      data,
    }, useGlobalFilter)
  const {globalFilter}=state

  



    async function fetchRecords(){
        try{
            let response=await Axios.get(`http://localhost:5050/viewrecords/${username}`)
            if(response.data.status==="ok"){
             
              setRecords(response.data.data);

            }
            else if(response.data.status==="error"){
                alert(response.data.error)

            }
        }
        catch(err){
            alert(err)
        }

    }

   


   
  return (
    <>
     <div><div className="topnav">
  <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
  <Link to={`/Records`}>Add Records</Link>


</div></div>
        <h1> {username}'s Records</h1>
       
        <div className='item-container'>
        <GlobalFilter  filter={globalFilter} setFilter={setGlobalFilter}/>
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row)
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
              })}
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
      </div>

    
    
    
    </>
  )
}
```

```js
import {useState} from 'react'

export  function GlobalFilter({filter,setFilter}) {
    const [val,setVal]=useState(filter)
  return (
    <span>
        Search: {""}
        <input value={filter || ""}
        type="text"
        onChange={(e)=>{setVal(e.target.value);setFilter(e.target.value)}}
        placeholder="Search by any Heading..."
        />
    </span>
  )
}
```

When I reload my View Records component in browser, the data is not displayed:

[image: When I reload my View Records component in browser, the data is not displayed]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because you need to add `records` as a useMemo dependancy as your initial `records` is an empty array, your data declaration should be

```js
const data = useMemo(() => records, [records])
```